# Closest Pair of Points Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am currently working on implementing the closest pair of points algorithm in C++. That is, given a list of points (x, y) find the pair of points that has the smallest Euclidean distance. I have done research into this and my understanding of the algorithm is the following (please correct me if I'm wrong):

Split the array of points down the middle
Recursively find the pair of points with the minimum distance for the left and right halves.
Sort the left and right halves by y-coordinate, and compare each point on the left to its 6 closest neighbors (by y-coordinate) on the right. There is some theoretical stuff behind this, but this is my understanding of what needs to be done).

I've gotten the recursion part of the algorithm to work, but am struggling to find an efficient way to find the 6 closest neighbors on the right for each point on the left. In other words, given two sorted arrays, I need to find the 6 closest numbers in Array B for each point in array A. I assume something similar to merge sort is required here, but haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A colleague of mine showed me these notes on [Computational geometry](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/754/Lects/754lects.pdf). Interesting stuff, could be useful for you.

Comment: I remember this from [CLRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms). A divide and conquer method. And yeah, I remember the 6 (or was it 7? points) but I don't remember the details. Anyway, if you have access to this book, the solution is in there.

Answer (score 4):

Let `dist = min(dist_L, dist_R)` where `dist_L, dist_R` are the minimum distances found in the left and right sets, respectively.

Now to find the minimum distance where one point is on the left half and the other on the right half, you only need to consider points whose x-coordinates are in the interval `[x_m - dist, x_m+dist]`.

The idea now is to consider the 6 closest points in this interval. So sort the points by y-coordinate for each point, look forward at the next 6. This will result in an `O(nlog^2(n))` running time.

You can further improve upon this to `O(nlogn)` by speeding up the sorting process. To do this, have each recursive call also return a sorted list of the points. Then to sort the entire list, you just have to merge the two sorted lists. An observant reader would notice that this is precisely merge sort.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I was sorting the two arrays by y-coordinate separately and trying to compare the points in the left array to the 6 closest points in the right array, for which there is no efficient way of doing. Got everything working perfectly.

Comment: Ok the one problem I'm still having is how to implement merge sort into my recursion. The base case for the recursion of my algorithm are sublists with size 2 and 3 (as far as I know, it would make no sense to have a base case of 1, because the minimum distance between a point an itself would have no significance). The base case for the recursive portion of merge sort seems to be 1. So how could I combine these two different types of recursion?

Comment: For a sublist of length 2 or 3, just sort the list manually. You don't need to use merge sort to do this.

Comment: How do you find the six point closest in y-coordinate? I can only think of binary search, but that cost log n time, which will result in O(n log^2 n) time as well, even if merge sort is piggybacked on the algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want a [quad tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

Comment: None of the research I've done into this algorithm mentions anything about using a quad tree.

Comment: None the less, it is a natural way to organize a cloud of 2d points.  If you has such a tree, you can get a rough gauge of how close two points are by the level of the smallest subtree that contains them both: close points will appear under deep subtrees.  This lets you prune the list of pairs you need to check to find the closest.